# Trailing slashes problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

When I type this "http://example.com/Hello%20There/" , it displays the
index page wich is : "http://example.com/Hello%20There/index.html" .

Well, what I want to do is when the user types "http://example.com/Hello%20There" 
(so like the first one except it doesn't have a trailing slash).

I tried many things and specially regular expressions, but nothing works because I think
that the server stops the reg exp process when he finds a space ("%20" in the URL).

I tried this reg exp:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
rewriteEngine On rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\ (.*html)$ 
rewriteRule ^.*$ %1-%2 [E=space_replacer:%1-%2] 
rewriteCond %{ENV:space_replacer}!^$ 
rewriteCond %{ENV:space_replacer}!^.*\ .*$ 
rewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:space_replacer} [R=301,L]
```

and also put:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

in the "mod_dir" module of Apache.

So, my question is:
- How to tell to the server to add a trailing slash when the user types an url
without a trailing slash;$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make a character optional by appending the `?` quantifier to it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.html
```

Now both `/foobar` and `/foobar/` would be rewritten to `/foobar/index.html`.

But it would be better if you use just one spelling, with or without the trailing slash, and redirect the other one:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

These rules either remove or add a missing trailing slash and do a permanent redirect.

Comment: You missed parentheses in second rewrite rule.

Comment: Please, which is the final combination of rules to be used? I'm really interested with this question, and I can't get it running ok... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I was using mod_alias to set up a subsite.  Turns out, I needed to make a second alias without the trailing slash so that it would work correctly.  Looked something like this:

```
Alias /forum/ "/var/www/forum"
Alias /forum "/var/www/forum"

<Directory "/var/www/forum">
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In Ubuntu, I had to edit the */etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf* file with these lines, then restart apache.  Couldn't find this answer anywhere on the web; I just stumbled onto it myself as mod_rewrite wasn't working and the DirectorySlash command didn't help either.  I was appending a non-Drupal program as a subsite under a Drupal installation, which is what kicked off all this madness in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use trailing slash to define an alias.

Both URLs http://example.com/myalias1 and http://example.com/myalias1/ would work fine.

Example:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf            

Alias /myalias1 "/path/to/folder1"
```