# Who adds a slash at the end of my url?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, user-agent

I'm using mod_rewrite to rewrite **/products** to **/products.php**. I've got this code in **/.htaccess**

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z]+)$ /$1.php [PT,L]
```

Unfortunately there is also a folder **/products/** on my server.

My problem is, when I try to access **http://mydomain.com/products** my request is redirected to **http://mydomain.com/products/** and showing me an error because I don't have an index for that directory.

Who is redirecting me? Apache, my UserAgent?
How do I prevent that this happens without changing the folder name or the rewrite rule?

Comment: Using mod_rewrite how? Show us the `mod_rewrite` rules please - in some cases, existing files and folders take precedence over mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look up the "DirectorySlash Directive".

> The DirectorySlash directive
>   determines whether mod_dir should
>   fixup URLs pointing to a directory or
>   not.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

You could also try adding an optional slash to you rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z]+)/?$ /$1.php [PT,L]
```

[Trailing slashes problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006186/trailing-slashes-problem)

Comment: I added "DirectorySlash Off" to the .htaccess file, but it's still redirecting.

Comment: @esel try the other solution. maybe its easier for you.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the same idea I got from Marms post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably enabled [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) on your Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser is adding the trailing slash after your request if it doesn't by ".something" because it thinks it is a folder. To avoid this, your rewrite rule should look like this:

RewriteRule /products(.*)$ /index.php?page=products

OR

RewriteRule /products /index.php?page=products

That way, it will rewrite every request with "/products" in it, with or without the trailing slash.

The only thing is your folder /products/ will not be accessible by an http request. If you want so, you must change the name of the folder or the page name.

Comment: Thanks. I can change my rule to RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z]+)\/?$ /$1.php [PT,L] so only /products and /products/ is rewritten, not other requests to the folder.