# Docker and Apache - Redirect 301 and trailing slash

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile

I hope that I can find help here because I'm little lost since some days...

I'm trying to put a PHP application in a Docker container.

So I'm using this image: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
(Especially the **php:7-apache** tag). This way I have PHP and Apache in the same container.

So my problem is that when I'm accessing a URL without a trailing slash I've a wrong redirection with add a slash but use the container IP address which is not accessible on the Docker Host.

Example:

- http:// localhost/admin -> redirection problem
- http:// localhost/admin/ -> works great

As you can see in this screenshot, there is a automatic redirection with the local IP of the container, but it's not accessible: we have a timeout in the web browser.

[image: console screenshot]

In this case the container IP address was `172.17.0.2`

(My container is published on my host on port `80`, so I'm accessing it with localhost like standard docker way)

My VirtualHost is quite simple:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Do you have ideas for this problem ?
I think I remember that the `301` redirection is a normal behavior of Apache because of `mod_dir` ? But why is it using container local IP ?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english!

Comment: Try adding `ServerName localhost`

Comment: Also follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006186/trailing-slashes-problem

Comment: @TarunLalwani ServerName solved my issue! Thank you very much! Have some time to explain me why in few words ? Or keywords to search for an explanation ? I'm not sure to understand why it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your virtual Host you are missing below

```
ServerName localhost
```

When that is missing Apache will try to determine the hostname itself and use the IP instead. Since this runs under a docker container the IP will be something like `172.17.0.2` which is not reachable through your browser.

That is why adding a `ServerName` is required, so that when apache has to send a redirect request it can create the correct URL of that redirect